# why used "simple present" instead of "simple past" or "present perfect"

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple, present-simple

I didn't understand. Why did they use "simple present" instead of "present perfect" in this *"Although I do not understand much yet"*?. The Paragraph is below.

> Nepal is a fascinating country, but I have a great deal to learn. Everything is so different, and I am trying to adapt to the new way of life here. I am learning a little bit of the language to make communication easier; unfortunately, I don't learn foreign languages quickly. ***Although I do not understand much yet***, I believe that I am gradually improving.

I thought he was trying to learn language from when she arrived there to now (so why not use the present perfect)?

Comment: Please explain why you think this is incorrect?  The author describes his/her **current** state of mind, so the simple present seems the most appropriate.

Comment: I thought he was trying to learn language from when she arrived there to now. @Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is describing his or her *current* state of mind, rather than an ongoing process.  In this way it's similar to other expressions of state, such as:

> The ocean **is** calm today.
>
> The wind **blows** gently through the open door.
>
> I finally **get** what my father told me long ago.

In English "understanding" is usually expressed as a state of mind, rather than an ongoing process. It is possible to use the present perfect "have understood" but usually in a conditional, and/or in relation to some other event.

> If I **have understood** you correctly, you want to travel to Nepal.
>
> Now that I **have understood** how he plays the game, I think I can beat him.

If you want to talk about the process of learning, from some time in the past until the present, you can use the expression "come to understand":

> Although I **have come to understand** much of the language since I arrived, I'm far from fluent.

Again, since "understand" is an expression of *state*, the simple past does not work for something you still understand.  Instead us it to describe something you *did* understand in the past:

> When I lived there, I **understood** much of the language, but sadly I've forgotten most of it.

Comment: I have learned that simple present using as repeated actions or generalizations. But why we use simple present in these sentences. "The wind blows gently through the open door.
I finally get what my father told me long ago."  I looked from here but i didn't see similiar. https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html